# How to log number of running thread in an iOS app?

Tags: ios, concurrency, nsthread, sigabrt

Getting SIGABRT due to big number of threads inside my app.
I need to log the number of thread running currently inside my iOS app.
I don't want to use profiler and breakpoints stuff.

Comment: are you using GCD to create threads?

Comment: If you pause, using the debugger, you'll be able to see all threads in the debug window. Or do you want to log them while executing?

Comment: If you are using XCode 5 then you can see the visual graph of number of threads and load of each thread in Debug Navigator in your XCode.

Comment: @dev gr This can be due to few other reasons as well. Can you post the crash logs? May be it can give some hint.

Comment: @Andrew I want to log them while executing.

Comment: @Amar my concern is not the error I am getting. But this error is due to creation of large number of threads inside app.

Answer (score 1):

Try it with this 
http://web.mit.edu/darwin/src/modules/xnu/osfmk/man/task_threads.html

```
    #import <mach/mach_types.h>
    #import <mach/mach_traps.h>
    #import <mach/mach.h>
    thread_act_array_t threads;
    mach_msg_type_number_t thread_count;
    task_t self = mach_task_self();

    /* Get a list of all threads */
    if (task_threads(self, &threads, &thread_count) == KERN_SUCCESS) {
        //thread_count should be populated.
    }
```

Also you'll have to do some memory management on some of these.